# How to detect Route changes at root level with or without parameter at child level angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have Read Number of questions related to same issue but none of them found right for my use case

i am using `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",` with RC-4 angular2, i have to make some condition based logic according to route change also at the child route change how to do it ?

i have tried various method including

- this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {..}
- this.router.changes((res) => {..}

but none of them works for me, how to fix it ?

Comment: what do u want to do? what is not working?

Comment: @micronyks i want to call one function on every time when routing called and want to get previous and current Url on routing. so that i am able to make some logic on the basis of routing.

Comment: So I'm sure `this.router.events.subscribe` will work. could you please reproduce in plunker?

Comment: it works but does't give me the desired result, i gives `NavigationStart, NavigationEnd....` i just want url alias.